# Laravel 5.8 Eloquent Model Relationship error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship between two models, User and Follower. 
User hasMany Follower, and Follower belongsTo User. 
In my followers table in the database I have two columns, follower_id and following_id. Both these columns refer to the id column in the users table.

My follower and users table

```
followers

      id
      follower_id
      following_id

 users
      id
      name
      username
```

User Model

```
public function followers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Follower', 'follower_id');
}

public function followings(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Follower', 'following_id');
}
```

Follower Model

```
 public function user(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

In a test controller I am doing this:

```
$followed = Follower::find(2);
```

From here, I would like to select one of the columns, follower_id or following_id, and access the user that this particular row belongs to by using $followed->user->name. How would I go about that? Since I need to select a column before accessing, I am a little bit confused. 
What can I do to access the data I need?

Comment: Can you `dd($followed)` to check result instance and show here.

Comment: Yes. I am currently echoing this variable as such: {{$followed}} and I get the row from the DB returned. I just realized, I have got two columns there that are 'follower_id' and 'following_id', both of which are pointing to the users table as foreign keys of the users table id column. I will revise my question accordingly

Comment: Use this query to check `$query = Follower::with('user')->findorFail(2)`. Then `dd($query)`, you should see user instance in `relation` row. If not, show your User and Follower table and model here

Comment: $query returns: "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null". I have added those items to the question above

Comment: I am missing return statements in my Follower model. I just realized that. Thank you for putting in the time and helping out though! Really appreciate that!

Comment: You set wrong at all relationship. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your table should be :

```
followers

      id
      follower_id
      following_id
      user_id

 users
      id
      name
      username
```

In your Follower model :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Follower::class, 'user_id');
}
```

In your User model :

```
public function follower()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Then you can query like this :

```
$follower = Follower::with('user')->findorFail(2);
$user_name = $follower->user->name;
```

Comment: I tried this and it only return "trying to get property of non-object:

Comment: Sorry, I've mistake. Edited !

Comment: in the Follower model, one follow belongsTo a user though right? A follow doesn't hasMany users?

Comment: I answer base on your question and your relationship. In the right way, the relationship should be Many to Many. User hasMany Follower and Follower also hasMany User(Following).